# What is a recent way of running a daemon service in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

*I have seen a few very old posts, like
[How to launch a native server application (ELF) on a rooted Android at/after boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8524666/)
with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920463/ and this questions [Android daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2801584) which both touch on my issue but not really give an answer what I need to do. Also since there are only a few questions on this topic either this is so obviously simple that there is no need to ask a question or I'm not searching with the correct terminology*

**I have a natively built application which I run as root on an Android(AOSP) development board.**

Starting this program from the console works fine but I would like it to start automatically in the background on boot-up.

- What would be a simple way of starting my process in the background at startup?
- What is be the currently recommended way of doing it?

Comment: The [initrc](https://web.archive.org/web/20100513023326/http://www.androidenea.com/2009/08/init-process-and-initrc.html) approach is still valid and fully supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem. *My tool builds in the aosp tree.*

- added a file `mytool.rc` this file is pushed to `/etc/init`

```
on boot
start myservice
service myservice /bin/mytool
   user root
   seclabel u:r:su:s0
   disabled
```

- added rc-file to `Android.bp`

```
cc_binary {
    name: "mytool",
    init_rc: ["mytool.rc"],
    defaults: ["mytool_defaults"],
    srcs: [
        "mytool.cpp",
    ],
}
```

- Temporary set SELinux to permissive mode by running shell command `setenforce 0`
- service is started with shell command `start mytool`